# android: create a new activity with xml page

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

I want to create a new activity. My default has two files `MainActivity.xml` with `MainActivity.java`. But, If i created a new activity only `.java` files are created in `/src/` path no `.xml` files are created in `res/layout` folder.

Help me to create an activity with `java` and `xml` as well ?

Comment: You don't need to create a java file....Right click your Project-New-Android Activity....An activity consists of both java and xml file....Seems you are quite new to android

Comment: Or you can also create an android XML file and extend activity class to your java class..Right click your Project-New-Android XML File

Comment: @user2648429 Check my answer i've just updated it, remember to accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create a manually a `newactivity.xml` in the res/layout folder then after that you can create a newActivity.java like this :

```
public class NewActivity extends Activity{
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newactivity);
}
}
```

Comment: should be `R.layout.newactivity` and not `R.layout.newactivity.xml` and your class must extend activity.

Comment: answer for this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032404/android-navigate-to-another-activity-when-button-clicked

Answer (score 2):

On Mac:

1. Right click on your package
2. New -> Other... 

   ( or Command + N )
3. Choose: Android -> Android Activity, click Next
4. Select a template (i.e Blank Activity), click Next
5. Enter Activity Name (i.e NewActivity), click Finish or Next

By this way, you can create java class, xml file, add information to Manifest file, create new string in strings.xml, create new menu, etc...

I hope this will help :)